# C# Console Application Close Button vs Environment.Exit(0)

Tags: console

I have a server (Windows application) and a client (console application)

--- When I close the client application by closing close(red) button it updates the record instantly

--- **but when I close the client application from server by sending command to invoke Environment.Exit(0) it closes the client application but doesn't update the record on server application**...?

I would like to know that **what does close button uses to terminate the application... Is it different?**

and What should I use to exit console application?

Thanks in advance...